# cleanest way to call one function on a list of items

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

In python 2, I used `map` to apply a function to several items, for instance, to remove all items matching a pattern:

```
map(os.remove,glob.glob("*.pyc"))
```

Of course I ignore the return code of `os.remove`, I just want all files to be deleted. It created a temp instance of a list for nothing, but it worked.

With Python 3, as `map` returns an iterator and not a list, the above code does nothing.
I found a workaround, since `os.remove` returns `None`, I use `any` to force iteration on the full list, without creating a `list` (better performance)

```
any(map(os.remove,glob.glob("*.pyc")))
```

But it seems a bit hazardous, specially when applying it to methods that return something. Another way to do that with a one-liner and not create an unnecessary list?

Comment: Yep: `for x in glob.glob("*.pyc"): os.remove(x)`

Comment: If you do want to keep the list, then I think list comprehension is the canonical way to do it. You can write `map(func,items)` as `[func(x) for x in items]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change from `map()` (and many other functions from 2.7 to 3.x) returning a generator instead of a list is a memory saving technique. For most cases, there is no performance penalty to writing out the loop more formally (it may even be preferred for readability).

I would provide an example, but @vaultah nailed it in the comments: still a one-liner:

```
for x in glob.glob("*.pyc"): os.remove(x)
```