# How do you print output and save in a file using list comprehension?

Tags: python

Is there a way to write and print using list comprehension? If I were to use For loop, I can do multiple things inside the for loop.

For example,

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
write=open("test.txt",'w')
for i in list1:
    print (i**2)
    write.write(str(i**2)+"\n")
write.close()
```

How can I do the same thing using list comprehension? I can either print or write using list comprehension?

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
write=open("test.txt",'w')
teste=[write.write(str(i**2) +"\n") for i in list1]
write.close()
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.7. It would be great if you could answer for both version ( 2.7 and 3.6. Thanks, Shone

Comment: Why do you want to use a list comprehension? Only use a list comprehension to *build a list*, not to do other things.

Comment: I just wanted to know ( I am trying to learn list comprehension)  if there is a way to do multiple things with list while using list comprehension.

Comment: @Sam: there are ways, but those are pointless. Don't use list comprehensions to do side effects. They are great for building a list, bad for anything else.

Comment: Unless you're doing something like [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), it's a bad idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it. Thank you. I wanted to know because sometime if I am creating a list, I want to also see the output to check.

Comment: @Sam: then just print the list you just produced. Don't make things too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use list comprehension for side effects ([cleanest way to call one function on a list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023423/cleanest-way-to-call-one-function-on-a-list-of-items?s=13|0.0265)).

However, you would write all your data in 1 write instruction using `str.join`:

```
write.write("".join([str(i**2) +"\n" for i in list1]))
```

I wouldn't recomment that, though in the general case, because if `list1` is big, it creates the whole string in memory.

You can alternately use `writelines`

```
write.writelines("{}\n".format(i**2) for i in list1)
```

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function`, then `print(*(i ** 2 for i in list1), sep='\n', file=write)`

Comment: Thank you Jean-Francois. That's really nice to know that I could write in 1 line of code. Is there no way to do multiple stuff while using list comprehension?

Comment: I want add the following, I think you can also use tuple in there, like [(print("bla1"), print("bla2")) for i in list], but I wouldn't do it because, List comprehensions are only for generating data in list form, not for executing statements (or any other side effect, like writing to a file) multiple times. Use a for look for that.

Comment: I decided to refresh at a silly time and the original comment was deleted before I read it properly. What specifically is the `str.join()` discussion about?

Comment: @Sam the aim of list comprehensions is to create some data. using them for side effects works, but creates a useless list full of `None` and it's not faster, maybe slower.

Comment: @roganjosh: [List comprehension without \[ \] in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)

Comment: @roganjosh Martjin doesn't like it too chatty. It's just that passing a gencomp to `join` isn't faster because list has to be built anyway. Same goes for `sorted` BTW.

Comment: Just want to add here, that there is nothing magical about lines of code. We can at time be overzealous. Do not optimize for few lines of code if it is against readability and correctness.

Comment: Thank you!! I got it. it's a bad idea to use list comprehension for anything except creating list.

Comment: and think of this this way if you have 1000 line of code with many lines written line that, how would you feel coming back to it after 6 months and trying to figure out whats happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file using a generator expression like so:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

f = open('filename.txt', 'a').writelines(str(pow(i, 2)+"\n" for i in list1)
```